# SVG vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" artifacts

Tags: css, svg

`vector-effect` seem to cause artifacts. If you hover over the star, you can see how it leaves trails in latest release version of Chrome:

[image]

If I remove `vector-effect` the artifacts are gone.

The only way I was able to fix this is by setting `overflow: hidden` on the `svg` element during the animation, such that the corners which overflow the element bounding box because of the stroke thickness are hidden, which is not desired.

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.svg-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;  
}

.svg-wrapper:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.svg-wrapper svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="31, 25, 238, 226" stroke-width="10" stroke="red" >
    <polygon points="150,25 179,111 269,111 197,165 223,251 150,200 77,251 103,165 31,111 121,111" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Is this issue know? Looking forward for some good workarounds

Comment: If you want to know if the issue is known look for it in the [chrome bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)